# Как я могу сохранить файл word в формате dotx с помощью python?

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx, docxtpl

По моей работе мне нужно создать много файлов do**t**x для специализированной программы с некоторыми типичными данными. Я пытаюсь использовать популярные библиотеки, такие как docxtpl или python-docx, но, как я понимаю, они не поддерживают работу с файлами **dotx**. Я пробовал библиотеки Aspose.Words and Spire.Doc, но они не бесплатные и создают водяные знаки.
[image: пример ватермарки]

Мне нужен способ открывать файлы dotx и редактировать их или, по крайней мере, сохранять файлы docx в формате dotx с помощью Python в Windows.

Есть ли какие-либо дополнительные бесплатные библиотеки или адоны к популярным библиотекам, которые могут решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ на github библиотеки https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/363 надо добавить 2 строки. Это позволит сохранить в dotx формате.
Там еще вроде есть способ заставить открывать данные файлы, но я еще плох в программировании.

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('test.docx')
document_part = document.part
document_part._content_type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats officedocument.wordprocessingml.template.main+xml'
doc.save('test.dotx')
```